# Simplify algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I posted a question before about simplifying an algebraic expression, but then I realised that I may have overcomplicated the answer. I got to the following equation initially:

$\frac{x^2-1(x+h)(x+h)}{x^2(x+h)(x+h)h}$

But at this point, I expanded the expression. Could I have just simplified this, and if so, how?

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Looks like you've got some answers already.  I just want to point out that *expression* and *equation* are not synonyms.  You're simplifying an expression; an equation is an equality between two expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator is nicely factored, leave it. For the numerator, either:

- expand & simplify, then factor & simplify:
  $$\frac{x^2-(x^2+2xh+h^2)}{x^2(x+h)^2h}=-\frac{2xh+h^2}{x^2(x+h)^2h}=-\frac{(2x+h)h}{x^2(x+h)^2h}$$
- factor using $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and then simplify:
  $$\frac{x^2-(x+h)^2}{x^2(x+h)^2h}=\frac{(x-x-h)(x+x+h)}{x^2(x+h)^2h}=\frac{-h(2x+h)}{x^2(x+h)^2h}$$

You end up with:
$$-\frac{2x+h}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$

Comment: That was a lot simpler than what I did before. Thank you

Comment: Alright, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It simplifies to $$\frac{x^2-(x^2+2hx+h^2)}{x^2h(x^2+2hx+h^2)}=\frac{-2x-h}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$